# How do I give out a role when I click on a reaction? It doesn't work for me?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make sure that when you enter a command, a message is sent and a reaction is set, and those who click on the reaction get a role, but when you enter a command, nothing happens.
Here is the code itself:

```
 @client.command(pass_context=True)
 @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
 async def mp(self, ctx, payload):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Праздник вазилина', description='Нажми на реакцию что бы получить роль', colour=discord.Color.purple())

    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) # Возвращаем сообщение после отправки
    message.add_reaction('✅')
    
    member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) 

    emoji = str(payload.emoji) 
    roles = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLE[emoji],)


    await member.add_roles(roles)
    print('[SUCCESS] Пользователь {0.display_name} получил новую роль {1.name}'.format(member, role))

    
    await member.send('test')
```

Comment: your bot is not waiting for a reaction add, payload is simply a parameter here, you need an `on_raw_reaction_add` event to handle this

Comment: @Ceres but can I make a command in an event?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed make some kind of "event" in a command. However your code contains some errors that we have to take care of first.

**First:** If you want to add a reaction to a message you always have to prefix it with `await`, otherwise it won't work and you'll get the following error:

```py
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

**Second:** `member` and `emoji` don't make any sense here, because you didn't include an `event`. You also cannot use `payload`.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mp(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Праздник вазилина', description='Нажми на реакцию что бы получить роль',
                        colour=discord.Color.purple())

    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)  # Send embed
    await message.add_reaction('✅') # Add reaction

    roles = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=RoleID) # Replace it with the role ID

    check = lambda reaction, user: client.user != user # Excludes the bot reaction

    while True:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check) # Wait for reaction
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
            await user.add_roles(roles) # Add role
            print('[SUCCESS] Пользователь {0.display_name} получил новую роль {1.name}'.format(user, roles)) # Print

            await user.send('TEST') # Send message to member
```

To allow multiple reactions we built in a `while True` "loop".

Comment: Thank you very much) but when you click on the reaction, the role is not issued, discord intents is enabled

Comment: Have you passed the right ID? Have you also "imported" the intents into your code?