# The bot does not give out a role when you click on the reaction, there are no errors, how to fix it?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Good time of day, a message is created and a reaction is added, but when you click on it, the role is not issued.
Code:

```
@commands.command(aliases = ["меропртиятие"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mp(self, ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Праздник ', description='Нажми на реакцию что бы получить роль',
                        colour=discord.Color.purple())

    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)  
    await message.add_reaction('✅') 

    roles = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=839599224000610344) 

    check = lambda reaction, user: client.user != user 

    while True:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check) 
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
            await user.add_roles(roles) 
            print('[SUCCESS] Пользователь {0.display_name} получил новую роль {1.name}'.format(user, roles)) 

            await user.send('TEST')
```

Comment: Looks like the answer I made for your other question... As mentioned in the comments of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538132/how-do-i-give-out-a-role-when-i-click-on-a-reaction-it-doesnt-work-for-me) try to add the Intents to your code, check if the bot role is above the role you want to assign etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.on_reaction_add) event for this. Store the message id of the embed either in a database or file then check if the reaction_add's message id is that of the stored message_id. An example would be:

```py
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
    message_id = reaction.message.id
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅" and message_id == STOREDMESSAGEID:
        # the rest of the code
```